# Assert Timeout (in pytest)

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio

I've created a MultiLock and RMultiLock class (I've only found two Python libs with these, and they're intermixed with other things.) In any case, MultiLock is not reentrant, so it should block if a second acquire attempt is made with `blocking=True` in all cases, even from the same thread.

How do I test this? I'd be satisfied with a unit test that could do this with a positive `timeout`.

Is there a pytest `assert` that can test if a certain amount of time has elapsed? If not, how would I go about writing one? Would I need to do multithreading? Does the built-in `threading` module implement scheduling in a fair enough way that I can guarantee that an `acquire()` being blocked yields? If I were to use asyncio or gevent for this, would it yield?

Comment: What concept are you talking about? What difference between multilock and, say, `threading.Semaphore`

Comment: The specific use case is I have a ServiceGroup with Services. These Services have state (stopped, started, etc.). Each Service state is protected by a lock. I want to make sure that I can atomically start or stop the group of Services, so I created a MultiLock to wrap the Service locks. I know given that these Services are not shared with other ServiceGroups, this isn't necessary. But I wanted to explore the space.